# WebView using YouTube API

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, ads

I've developed a simple android app using WebView method. my string link is: [This](http://gurujibd.net/tube/)

Now my question is, can I upload my app that was developed by me using the above link? I'm not using AdMob ads at this moment. Can i use AdMob ads on this app? Please don't refer to AdMob policy link, I read that before, just need to hear from a real developer's experience.

Clarification: Can i use YouTube videos in my android application using WebView? Can i use AdMob ads? If AdMob is not allowed, can I use any other ad-networks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can play random youtube videos in Webview and put ads on the screen. But you can publish an app with only webview.

Warning- At first you will be able to publish the app with youtube with ads in webview but as soon as google detect it, your app will be removed.

Comment: thanks. but i need more clear think. can i publish my app using the webview method posted by above link? does this detect violation? suppose, i'm put the link posted above without google ads. i want to use my own ads but checked the contains with ads option?